# Deal with duplicates conditionally to an other column with r

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a big database, and I would like do deal with duplicates (without deleting any of them) conditionally to another column.
Here below a sample of my input :

```r
 name                              nb_participants
 INSTITUT BILA BILA                    10
 INSTITUT BILA BILA                    4
 INSTITUT BILA BILA                    NA
 INSTITUT NZUNDU                       3
 INSTITUT NZUNDU                       15
...
```

```r
structure(list(name = c("INSTITUT BILA BILA", "INSTITUT BILA BILA", "INSTITUT BILA BILA","INSTITUT NZUNDU","INSTITUT NZUNDU"), nb_participants = c(10, 4, NA,3,15)), row.names = c("1", "2","3","4","5"), class = "data.frame")
```

The wanted output is the following :

```r
 name                            nb_participants
 INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-1              10
 INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-2               4
 INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-3              NA
 INSTITUT NZUNDU 2-2                  3
 INSTITUT NZUNDU 2-1                 15
...
```

```r
structure(list(name = c("INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-1", "INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-2", "INSTITUT BILA BILA 2-3","INSTITUT NZUNDU 2-2","INSTITUT NZUNDU 2-1"), nb_participants = c(10, 4, NA,3,15)), row.names = c("1", "2","3","4","5"), class = "data.frame")
```

I have this command

```r
data$name<-ave(as.character(data$name), data$name, FUN=function(x) if (length(x)>1) paste0(x[1], '-', seq_along(x), '') else x[1])
```

But I do not know how to deal with ranking conditionally to another column. For now the only thing a I managed to do is with :

```r
data<-data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(nb_participants ==max(nb_participants))
```

Do you have any idea that could help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does the `"2-"` part of the sufix mean?

Comment: Also please provide a reproducible example of the input data

Comment: what did you try? do the ranking numbers have to be added to the character string in column 1 or can it be a different column? (subquestion: are you sure you need to keep the NA values in column 2? - it makes ranking quite a bit more involved if it is so)

Comment: -2 is to indicate the duplicates. Also I just added a reproductible example.  For the NA values I wanted to keep as many information as possible. However if it makes ranking to difficult, it is not essential for the analysis, so I guess I could do it without.

Comment: The standard way to do this is using `make.unique`, however although this serves it's purpose it won't look the same as what you proposed even with a custom `sep`. Is this function sufficient for you or would you rather create a custom function?

Answer (score 1):

This could help your problem ( use the package tidyverse for the syntax).
First if you want to sort your data by the nb_participant variable descending, do as following:

```
df <- df %>% arrange(name, desc(nb_participants))
```

Then, you must create the number of iteration by name:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

The id column will count for each occurences of the name variable.

If you want then to add this number to the name variable as you showed in your example you can simply do as following :

```
df$name <- paste(df$name, " 2- ", df$id, sep="")
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this also impacts not-duplicated rows

Comment: may be I could separate into 2 database the duplicates and the unique rows, and do this command on the duplicates database, and a rbind afterward to (re)combine the uniques and the duplicates?

Comment: with the following code : unique<-data %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n() == 1) and duplicates<-data %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n() > 1)

Comment: Yes that is a good way to split your data, maybe it could be useful to delete the observations with NA for nb_participants. But it depend on what you want